# Is it possible to have different separator color for each section in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to have different separator color for each section.

This is possible? Is there any way to achieve this?

I am currently working in Objective-C, and I achive to change the whole UITableView separator colors with this code:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Waiting for your answers

Comment: You can use a cell to separate two different section， the section header（footer）also can achieve your target。

Comment: Add a view with 1px height to the bottom of cell's content view. Set the unique background color. Hide the default separator.

Comment: As @pkc456 has mentioned, you can add UIButton, UIImageView or UIView with 1px size in cell and set it's color for each row

Comment: it is easier to add a custom 'separator' to your custom cells, and colour them based on which section has it.

Comment: I will try your different options and reply if they work

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tableView.frame.width, 0, 0)
```

real example

```
switch dataSource[indexPath.section] {
case .withoutSeparator(_, var elements):
  let cell: ServiceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
  cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tableView.frame.width, 0, 0)
  }
  return cell
case let .withSeparator(_, elements, _):
  let cell: ZoneCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
  return cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually create the custom UITableView which can help in doing this.
You need to override the drawRect code of UITableview and make this possible.